# Why do these booleans work in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, boolean

I'm just getting started with Python and wrote a simple "Rock, Paper, Scissors" game that works, but the way it compares the player and ai choices doesn't make sense to me. Their winning/losing conditions seem to be opposite of what I set them to.

```
#Rock Paper Scissors
import random

print("Welcome to Rock, Paper, Scissors!")
print()
print()
choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]

choices[0] < choices[1]
choices[1] < choices[2]
choices[2] < choices[0]

def game():
    player_choice = input("What will you choose?:  "  ).lower()
    print()
    ai_choice = random.choice(choices)
    who_chose = print("You chose",player_choice,"and the computer chose",ai_choice)

    if player_choice not in choices:
        print("Sorry, that is not a valid option, please choose again.")
        print()
        game()
    elif player_choice > ai_choice:
        who_chose
        print("The computer wins!")
        print()
    elif player_choice == ai_choice:
        who_chose
        print("It was a tie!")
        print()
    else:
        who_chose
        print("You Win!")
        print()
    play_again = input("Do you want to play again? (y/n): ").lower()
    if play_again in ["yes", "y"]:
        game() 
    else:
        print("Thanks for playing") 


game()
```

I set their hierarchy here:

```
choices[0] < choices[1]
choices[1] < choices[2]
choices[2] < choices[0]
```

But when I compare them, it seems to be backward here, but it works in occordance to the rules of Rock paper scissors:

```
elif player_choice > ai_choice:
        who_chose
        print("The computer wins!")
        print()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
choices[0] < choices[1]
choices[1] < choices[2]
choices[2] < choices[0]
```

< is a boolean operator, meaning it tries to compare the values and determine whether it's true or false, it is not an assignment. Try input one of those statements in your console. Python interprets the hierarchy of strings alphabetically.

The easiest way to do what you want that I can think of right now is creating a truth table.

```
#rock, paper, scissors
t=[0, 1, 0; #rock
   0, 0, 1; #paper
   1, 0, 0] #scissors
```

And index that as follows:

```
t[player_choice,ai_choice]
```

If it returns a 1, you have won.

Comment: Oh ok, that makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: Also, I was looking through it again, and if I understand you correctly, the reason it works now is because the length of the strings just happen to match with the winning conditions of the game? Example "scissors" is longer than "paper" so scissors beats paper?

Comment: Oh you are right, I just checked, and it actually does do something. Apperently python looks at the alphabetical order, so scissors beats paper because the 's' is further down the alphabet